# Header file contains function body, will lead to duplicated definition?

Tags: c++, function, duplicates, inline, definition

I've done a simple experiment, a ".h" file with a class definition and a funciton definition, as below:

```
$cat testInline.h
#pragma once
class C{
public:
    void f(){}
};
void g(){}
```

Then 2 users of this .h file:

```
$cat use01.cpp
#include"testInline.h"
void g01(){
    g();
    C obj1;
    obj1.f();
}

$cat use02.cpp
#include"testInline.h"
int main(){
    g();
    C obj2;
    obj2.f();
    return 0;
}
```

I compile them together and gets an error:

```
$g++ use01.cpp use02.cpp
duplicate symbol __Z1gv in:
    /var/folders/zv/b953j0_55vldj97t0wz4qmkh0000gn/T/use01-34f300.o
    /var/folders/zv/b953j0_55vldj97t0wz4qmkh0000gn/T/use02-838e05.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Looks really weird: I've used "#pragma once"，still I cannot stop compiler from reporting duplicated definition of g()(__Z1gv as name mangling)

Then I modified testInline.h->g() definition to be like:

```
inline void g(){}
```

Well, it compiles. Isn't it in C++ that "inline" keyword is basically useless, because compilers will decide whether it'll inline a function or not?

And，why C::f() with code in .h file doesn't report duplication, while a C-style function g() does? And why class C doesn't "have to" add "inline" for its "f()" function, while g() has to use "inline"?

Hope I've stated my question clearly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've used "#pragma once"，

Yes, you did. And each one of the two translation units effectively processed the header file exactly once. Each one would've done so even without the pragma, since each translation unit includes the header file just once.

`#pragma once` does not mean "include this header file in just one of the translation units being compiled". It means "include this header file once per translation unit, even if the translation unit directly, or indirectly, includes the header file two or more times". As such, each translation unit included the header file, and defined the functions/methods from the header file itself. Since the same function or method ended up being defined by both translation units you ended up with a duplicate at link time.

> Isn't it in C++ that "inline" keyword is basically useless, because
>   compilers will decide whether it'll inline a function or not?

It is true that the compiler decides whether the function actually gets inlined, or not. However, the `inline` keyword specifies whether the function definition is processed as if it were logically inlined for every use of it, and not actually defined. As such, using the `inline` keyword does not result in duplicate definitions since, logically, the function is inserted inline at its every reference.

It is true that Whether this actually happens, or whether the compiler produces non-inlined code, is up to the compiler. However, C++ requires that the function gets compiled "as if" it was inlined; so even if the compiler decides not to inline the function, it must take whatever steps are necessary to ensure that the duplicate non-inlined copies of the function does not result in an ill-formed program.

> And，why C::f() with code in .h file doesn't report duplication,

Because a class method defines inside the definition of the class is effectively an inline definition, even if the `inline` keyword is not explicitly specified.

Comment: "C++ requires that the function gets compiled "as if" it was inlined;", uh, consider a recursive function. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The `inline` keyword is not useless.  It's just that it doesn't necessarily control whether the function is actually inlined.

The `inline` keyword marks a function as possibly defined in multiple translation units.  (The definition and meaning must be the same in all of them.)  You should mark a function defined in a header file as `inline`.

A function defined within a class definition, like your `C::f`, is automatically considered "`inline`".